# Why doesn't a variable created with dplyr exist in the data frame?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am analyzing a Demographic and Health Survey data set. I am in the phase of creating variables. I created a variable using `dplyr` and `mutate`, but when I use the function exist to find out whether it is in the data frame, it does not exist. Why is this so?

```
datamatrix %>% mutate(hw70_1=case_when(hw70< -200 ~ 1, hw70>= -200 ~ 0))

# A tibble: 91,028 x 44
  X1 caseid order    b4 caseid.1 order.1  hw57 caseid.2 order.2  hw70
  <dbl> <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   <dbl> <chr>    <chr>   <dbl>
 1     1 1 11 ~ b4_01    NA 1 11  2  hw57_1     NA 1 11  2  hw70_1     NA
 2     2 1 21 ~ b4_01     1 1 21  1  hw57_1      4 1 21  1  hw70_1   -103
 3     3 1 21 ~ b4_01     2 1 21  9  hw57_1      2 1 21  9  hw70_1     51
 4     4 1 21 ~ b4_01     1 1 21 13  hw57_1     NA 1 21 13  hw70_1     NA
 5     5 1 21 ~ b4_01    NA 1 21 14  hw57_1     NA 1 21 14  hw70_1     NA
 6     6 1 41 ~ b4_01     2 1 41  2  hw57_1     NA 1 41  2  hw70_1     NA
 7     7 1 41 ~ b4_01     1 1 41  6  hw57_1     NA 1 41  6  hw70_1     NA
 8     8 1 41 ~ b4_01    NA 1 41  7  hw57_1     NA 1 41  7  hw70_1     NA
 9     9 1 51 ~ b4_01     1 1 51  2  hw57_1     NA 1 51  2  hw70_1     NA
10    10 1 61 ~ b4_01     2 1 61  1  hw57_1      9 1 61  1  hw70_1   9999
# ... with 91,018 more rows, and 34 more variables: caseid.3 <chr>,
#   order.3 <chr>, hw71 <dbl>, caseid.4 <chr>, order.4 <chr>, hw72 <dbl>,
#   caseid.5 <chr>, order.5 <chr>, hw73 <dbl>, v005 <dbl>, v013 <dbl>,
#   v020 <dbl>, v021 <dbl>, v022 <dbl>, v025 <dbl>, v044 <dbl>, v106 <dbl>,
#   v137 <dbl>, v190 <dbl>, v437 <dbl>, v438 <dbl>, v445 <dbl>,
#   v447a <dbl>, v453 <dbl>, v501 <dbl>, v502 <dbl>, v714 <dbl>,
#   d005 <dbl>, d104 <dbl>, d106 <dbl>, d107 <dbl>, d108 <dbl>, v213 <dbl>,
#   hw70_1 <dbl>

> exists("hw70_1")
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems:

- `exists("hw70_1")` tests whether a variable is present **in your workspace** (not inside some data frame/tibble)
- you haven't saved the results of your `mutate()` call.

Try something like:

```r
dm <- datamatrix %>% mutate(hw70_1=...)
"hw70_1" %in% names(dm)
## or
!is.null(dm[["hw70_1"]])
## or
exists("hw70_1", list2env(dm))
```

If you prefer, rather than creating a new, modified data frame (`dm` in the example above), you can overwrite/update `datamatrix` (`datamatrix <- datamatrix %>% mutate(...)`, or use the `%<>%` operator: `datamatrix %<>% mutate(...)`

Comment: Thank you for your support. I tried to create a new variable using hw70_1 and hw73_1 with a new modified data frame as suggested, but I am having a similar problem with an error that says hw73_1 does not exist. Why is this happening? 
>dm <- datamatrix %>% mutate(hw73_1=case_when(hw73< -200~1, hw73>= -200~0))
> exists("hw73_1", list2env(dm))
[1] TRUE
> dm <- datamatrix %>% mutate(hw74_1=case_when(hw70_1==0 & hw73_1==0 ~ 0, hw70_1==1 & hw73_1==1~ 1, TRUE ~ 99))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `hw74_1`.
x object 'hw73_1' not found
i Input `hw74_1` is `case_when(...)`.´

Comment: your last statement is not operating on the modified object `dm`.  You might be better off using the `%<>%` operator so that you update `datamatrix` as you go along.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you for pointing it out.